# CSS not found on localhost but it works with live server

Tags: css, node.js

I'm learning NodeJS, and I'm having trouble loading the CSS. It loads with live server, but not found with localhost.
Also doesn't load the JS file. I need to do the script in the html with  tag.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,500i,700,800i"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"
      integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <title>My House Rent</title>
  </head>
  <body>

...

    <h1>Index</h1>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".navbar-light .dmenu").hover(
          function () {
            $(this).find(".sm-menu").first().stop(true, true).slideDown(150);
          },
          function () {
            $(this).find(".sm-menu").first().stop(true, true).slideUp(105);
          }
        );
      });
    </script>
    <!-- <script src="./javascript.js"></script> -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Print:

[image: Print]

Explorer:

[image: Explorer]

Comment: The problem has to be somewhere in the server-side code.

Comment: @t.niese Do I have to do something in the server side?

Comment: Please add the code from server.js and router.js

Comment: Do you have any server-side code that servers up `style.css`?  Nodejs, by itself, does not serve ANY files so you must have a specific route or a generic route like `express.static()` in order to server static files.

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the no HTML tag uses or needs a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: @jfriend00 No I dont have any server up. Is not possible to do it without express?

Comment: @Rob I didn't get it

Comment: When you put this `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />` in your web page, they `style.css` has to come from somewhere.  Where is the web page coming from?  What is the URL in the URL bar when you're displaying the web page?